# Processing image stops mid-loop for no reason c#

Tags: c#, loops, image-processing

I have an image, and I want to take each square of 256X256 pixels, find the mean color, and draw that square with said color.
Problem: it seems that after the first square the processing suddenly stops, but after following the program I can see the indexes are just fine. I have no idea if the problem lies with file writing in my computer system, or a wrong use of the "Bitmap" class functions.

original:
[image: original image]

result:
[image: result image]

code:

```
        public const int big =256;
        public const int small = 16;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bt = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\mishe\Desktop\00_sorted images - training\general shores\agulhas_oli_2016146_lrg.jpg");
            Bitmap bt2 = bt;
            Color MeanColor;
            double r = 0;
            double g = 0;
            double b = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            //big loop to go over all image
            for (i = 0; i < bt.Height-257; i+=256)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < bt.Width-257; j+=256)
                {
                    /////////////////////////////
                    //small loop on 1 square to get the mean color of the area
                    for (int x = i; x < big; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = j; y < big; y++)
                        {
                            r += bt.GetPixel(x, y).R;
                            g += bt.GetPixel(x, y).G;
                            b += bt.GetPixel(x, y).B;
                        }
                    }
                    /////////////////////////////
                    r = r / Math.Pow(big, 2);
                    g = g / Math.Pow(big, 2);
                    b = b / Math.Pow(big, 2);
                    MeanColor = Color.FromArgb((int)r, (int)g, (int)b);
                    /////////////////////////////
                    //small loop on the same square to set the color
                    for (int x = i; x < big; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = j; y < big; y++)
                        {
                            bt2.SetPixel(x, y, MeanColor);
                        }
                    }
                    /////////////////////////////
                }
            }
            bt2.Save(@"C:\Users\mishe\Desktop\compressed image.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
//small loop on 1 square to get the mean color of the area
for (int x = i; x < big; x++)
```

After the first square, x will be 256, so it won't do the small loop.

I think you want:

```
for (int x = i; x < i + big; x++)
```

Or your small loop could be:

```
for (int x = 1; x < big; x++)
```

and then add the large and small values inside the loop:

```
 r += bt.GetPixel(i + x, j + y).R;
```